# Induction Proof with Binomial Coefficient

Tags: induction

For all n > 0 prove that ${2n}\choose{n}$ < $4^n$

It seems like a simple proof but I'm not sure how to continue it.

What I have so far:

Base Case:

Let n=1  ${2}\choose{1}$ = 2
 $4^1$ = 4
  2 < 4

Inductive Step: Assume ${2(x+1)}\choose{x+1}$ < $4^{x+1}$

Left side:  $\frac{(2x+2)!}{(x+1)1(x+1)!}$

Comment: Do we have to use induction?

Comment: No, I think I can prove any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the inductive step:

$$
\begin{align*}
\binom{2n+2}{n+1}
&= \frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!\,(n+1)!} \\
&= \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2} \times \frac{(2n)!}{n!\,n!} \\
&= \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2} \binom{2n}{n} \\
&= \frac{2(2n+1)}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n} \\
&= \frac{4n + 4 - 2}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n} \\
&= \left(4 - \frac{2}{n+1}\right)\binom{2n}{n} \\
&< 4\binom{2n}{n} \\
&< 4^{n+1}.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Why are you multiplying by the  (2n choose n)

Comment: I'm confused why you're multiplying everything by ${2n}\choose{n}$

Comment: @JanoyCresva: I edited my answer. Is it more understandable  ?

Comment: It's still not clear to me, I don't know if I'm missing something. Where is the  ${(2n)!}\choose{n!n!}$ coming from? I meant that as a fraction

Comment: $$(2n+2)! = (2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)...3\times2\times1= (2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!$$
and $$(n+1)! = (n+1)(n)(n-1)...3*2*1=(n+1)n!$$ $$\therefore (n+1)!(n+1)!= (n+1)n!(n+1)n!=(n+1)^2 n!$$

using those two you can change $\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+1)!} = \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2} \times \frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$

Comment: Ok I think I got it. I'm still trying to get used to the notation for these. Thanks

Comment: @JanoyCresva No Problem